# How to find the number of ways of picking a subset of $\{a, b, c, \ldots,z, 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9\}$ of two elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am solving problems for discrete math and came across this one.

> Find the number of ways of picking a subset of $\{a, b, c, \ldots, z, 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9\}$ of two elements?

My solution is $36C2$ as I am picking two elements out of $36$. However, I found online that the answer is $26C2 \cdot 10C2$.

Why would that be the case and not my solution?

[image]

Comment: It's usually a good practice for the question to include a link to the place where you found this "solution" on line, either to let people see if there is any other relevant information there, or (in the worst case) as a warning to other people who might rely on the same "solution".

Comment: There seems to be a typographical error in your question.  The incorrect solution you found online states that there are $\binom{26}{2} + \binom{10}{2}$ such subsets, not $\binom{26}{2}\binom{10}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The way the question is phrased, I agree with what you did. What I can add is that $ 26\choose 2$ +$ 10 \choose 2$ is the number of ways that you can pick two elements from the set that satisfy the rule of being both letters or both numbers. Your answer allows picking one letter and one number.

Comment: The word subset does not indicate I have to pick a letter and a number, does it? It just means that every element of the subset must be an element of the given set.

Comment: I agree 100%. If there is some restriction on what elements you have to pick, it should be somewhere in the context.